# My infix is fast and dumb

Tags: riddle, rhyme

- My prefix is all a sound.
- My suffix is all around.
- My infix is fast and dumb.
- My whole is thin and numb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer:

> Hair

My prefix is all a sound.

> Ha - the sound one makes when laughing

My suffix is all around.

> Air - it is all around us

My infix is fast and dumb.

> AI - artificial intelligence is very fast at computing and is often dumb (without sufficient data)

My whole is thin and numb.

> Hair - each strand is thin and does not feel pain